# Rails - console says 'rendered' but the redirect not happening

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, api, controller, request

I have written a Service Module that makes an API request, returns either a string with the error or a hash with parameters and included it in the Controller.

```
def create
    @new_params = ApiRequest.create_login(params, customer_secret) #this returns either a string or hash
    request_error? #if it's a string, it should immediately render :new
    params[:login] = @new_params #substitutes the params from the form with the API response
    @login = current_user.logins.new(login_params).save
  end
```

Here's how it should redirect without trying to save

```
def request_error?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_params.is_a? String
        @error = @new_params
        format.html { render :new, notice: @error }
      end
    end
end
```

The problem is, in the console it says that it `rendered :new` (or even `redirected_to new_login_path` - if I were to use this instead of render) but the page doesn't even reload, just nothing happens. And even though it should have exited the create action earlier with render :new, it still tries to save the @login and fails.

My guess is that the long API Request breaks the action (>300ms for the whole controller action). What should I do in order to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It had nothing to do with the controller or request, the `form_with` was submitted with Ajax by default, in order to respond to html I had to specify `local: true`. The previous comment solves the 'exit early out of the controller action' problem.

Comment: arg this! This saved me, stuck for at least an hour. Form_with needs local:true to redirect!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are trying to render but not stopping the progress of the controller action by returning.

Consider replacing the `request_error?` method being inlined to the action:

```
def create
  @new_params = ApiRequest.create_login(params, customer_secret) #this returns either a string or hash
  respond_to do |format|
    if @new_params.is_a? String
      @error = @new_params
      format.html { render :new, notice: @error }
    end
  end
  params[:login] = @new_params #substitutes the params from the form with the API response
  @login = current_user.logins.new(login_params).save
end
```

Since you don't return when rendering within the conditional, the action continues and goes on to save your login.

To avoid this, you should return when you render within your conditional.

```
def create
  @new_params = ApiRequest.create_login(params, customer_secret) #this returns either a string or hash
  respond_to do |format|
    if @new_params.is_a? String
      @error = @new_params
      format.html { render :new, notice: @error and return }
    end
  end
  params[:login] = @new_params #substitutes the params from the form with the API response
  @login = current_user.logins.new(login_params).save
end
```

Note, you can't do this if you continue to use the method `request_error?` as if you return within that method you pass control back to the action. Instead, you'd need to return a boolean, say, to determine whether you have rendered, like:

```
def request_error?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @new_params.is_a? String
        @error = @new_params
        format.html { render :new, notice: @error }
        return true
      else
        return false
      end
    end
end
```

Then, return early if there is a request error:

```
  def create
    @new_params = ApiRequest.create_login(params, customer_secret) #this returns either a string or hash
    return if request_error? 
    params[:login] = @new_params #substitutes the params from the form with the API response
    @login = current_user.logins.new(login_params).save
  end
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: Ok, the problem was the form submitting with Ajax. The new `form_with` in Rails 5 has `remote: true` by default, so in order to respond to html you have to specify `local: true`.